# Micrstrategy dont see picture in developer

Tags: report, microstrategy

In Microstrategy 10.9 I need to insert pictures as header and footer of a document. I can reach pictures with browser (stored in TomCat and IntelligenceServer folders), but cann't from Developer. I get red x. Even on preview I get - Image not Found

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To see the image in Developer (the old Desktop) you should copy the images in the local installation folder of MicroStrategy or in the iServer `images\` folder. [More information can be found here](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB37807-Best-practices-on-how-to-reference-image-using-relative).

You don't see the image in Developer because you are trying to reach a folder protected by the MicroStrategy authentication, but the url request is coming from your local machine which doesn't have an authenticated session.

Comment: The problem is that files are in all locations, which mentioned in you provided link (I was working based on their documentation), but when it still wasn't working as expected I asked the question here. If I try to reach a picture from Microstrategy, but it doesn't use authentification, how this problem could be solved?

Comment: We you use MicroStrategy Developer the picture should be on your machine. The image path should be something like `../images/picture.jpg`or `./images/picture.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you're trying from a browser that is on the same machine as the Developer, and using the same address for the image ?

Can you check if the image is displayed correctly when the document is seen from a browser ?

Comment: Yes. That is the problem, that on the same machine I see a picture in browser, but not in Developer. As well I can load any random picture from internet.

Comment: Can you give an example of the link you're using for the image ?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. THe link looks like: http://10.65.11.11:8080/MicroStrategy/images/picture.jpg